# forcing grid-template-row to expand upwards

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a layout where the entire grid takes up 100% of the viewport height (minus 7rem at the top for the menu) and 100% of the viewport width, overlaid over this, I have some text boxes, see image 1 below, the issue I have is the rows defined "auto" are scaling downwards when the viewport width becomes too small to display the text, see image 2 below, you can see that the grids properly expand to keep the text in the box, however, it expands downwards, I want it to expand upwards, any suggestions?

codepen: https://codepen.io/roomwillow/pen/oNBawvR

Image 1 (longer width page, notice how the grid is within the confines of the viewport):
[image: image 1]

Image 2 (shorter width page, notice how the grid is now overflowing the viewport, instead of expanding upwards):
[image: image 2]

HTML:

```
<div id="landing">
        <h2 id="box_1_head">A Strong Heading</h2>
        <p  id="box_1_p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <div id="box_1_background"></div>

        <h3  id="box_2_text">Solutions for COVID-19 Production</h3>
        <a  id="box_2_button" class="button1" href="covid-solutions.hmtl">Learn More</a>
        <div id="box_2_background"></div>
        <video id="landing_video" width="1920" height="1080" autoplay muted loop>
            <source src="/content/black_white_test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#landing {
    height: calc(100vh - 7rem);
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2.5rem 3rem auto 7rem 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 40% auto auto 6rem auto 3rem 10rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#box_1_head {
    margin-left: 1rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    max-width: 27rem;
    grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 4;
    z-index: 4;
}
#box_1_p {
    margin-left: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    margin-right: 4rem;
    max-width: 30rem;
    grid-area: 3 / 2 / 5 / 4;
    z-index: 4;
}
#box_1_background {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    grid-area: 2 / 2 / 5 / 4;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 70%;
}
#box_2_text {
    margin-left: 1rem;
    margin-top: 0.45rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.45rem;
    grid-area: 5 / 3 / 6 / 4;
    z-index: 4;
    max-width: 30rem;
}
#box_2_button {
    margin-left: 1rem;
    grid-area: 6 / 3 / 7 / 4;
    justify-self: start;
    align-self: start;
    z-index: 4;
}
#box_2_background {
    grid-area: 4 / 3 / 7 / 5;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 3;
    opacity: 40%;
}
#landing_video video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `grid`, you should use it also to keep that room for your header/nav .

Then, `calc()` is unnecessary but `clamp()` can be usefull.

here is an idea where the extra wrapper could be body.

```css
/* new / update */
.wrapper {
  min-height:100vh;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-rows:auto 1fr;
}
#landing {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2.5rem 3rem auto 7rem 1fr;/* Is it not a lot for small screens ? */
    /*|*/grid-template-rows: clamp(40vmin, 0px, 30vh) auto auto 6rem auto 3rem 10rem;
}


/* yours */

#box_1_head {
    margin-left: 1rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    max-width: 27rem;
    grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 4;
    z-index: 4;
}
#box_1_p {
    margin-left: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    margin-right: 4rem;
    max-width: 30rem;
    grid-area: 3 / 2 / 5 / 4;
    z-index: 4;
}
#box_1_background {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    grid-area: 2 / 2 / 5 / 4;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 70%;
}
#box_2_text {
    margin-left: 1rem;
    margin-top: 0.45rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.45rem;
    grid-area: 5 / 3 / 6 / 4;
    z-index: 4;
    max-width: 30rem;
}
#box_2_button {
    margin-left: 1rem;
    grid-area: 6 / 3 / 7 / 4;
    justify-self: start;
    align-self: start;
    z-index: 4;
}
#box_2_background {
    grid-area: 4 / 3 / 7 / 5;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 3;
    opacity: 40%;
}
#landing_video video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / ;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"><!-- or just body -->
  <header>Let's be any height if not 7rem<nav></nav></header>
  <div id="landing">
        <h2 id="box_1_head">A Strong Heading</h2>
        <p  id="box_1_p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <div id="box_1_background"></div>

        <h3  id="box_2_text">Solutions for COVID-19 Production</h3>
        <a  id="box_2_button" class="button1" href="covid-solutions.hmtl">Learn More</a>
        <div id="box_2_background"></div>
        <video id="landing_video"   autoplay muted loop>
            <source src="/content/black_white_test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
</div>
```

About `clamp()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp()